# Build a Turing machine that will count the units written in a row (without omissions)

Tags: turing-machines

Build a Turing machine that will count the units written in a row (without omissions) (their number does not exceed n) and write their number in the number system with the base n +1, here n=3+[N](mod 13) and N =(your number in the group list)+(your number groups).Build a Turing machine that will count the units recorded in a row (without omissions).

```
N = 7 + 4208 = 4215; n= 3 + (4215 mod 13) = 7;
n + 1 = 8 number system.
```

My teacher says you can't write like that, she says it's a write off job, even though it's a lie.

```
q0 S0 0 0 q14
q0 1 R q1
q1 S0 L q14
q1 1 2 q2
q2 2 L q2
q2 1 S0 q2
q2 S0 R q2
q2 2 R q3
q3 S0 L q14
...
q12 7 R q13
q13 S0 L q14
```

and I wrote the check.

```
Verification:
Given: 1111
0) 1111
1) q0 S0 0 q14 1111
2) q0 1 R q1 1111
3) q1 S0 L q20 1111
...
17) q5 4 L q14 34
18) q5 3 S0 q6 4
19) q6 S0 R q6 4
20) q6 4 R q7 4
21) q7 S0 L q14 4.
```

And with the degree of the number, I thought I didn't need to do it, because it's fine as it is
I'm trying to write a new method:

```
  q0 1 s0 q0
  q0 s0 R q1
  q1 s0 1 qk
  q1 1 s0 q1
  q1 s0 R q2
  q2 s0 2 qk
  q2 2 s0 q2
  q2 s0 R q3
  q3 s0 3 qk
  q3 3 s0 q3
  q3 s0 R q4
  q4 s0 4 qk
  q4 4 s0 q4
  q4 s0 R q4
  q5 s0 5 qk
  q5 5 s0 q5
  q5 s0 R q6
  q6 s0 6 qk
  q6 6 s0 q6
  q6 s0 R q7
  q7 s0 7 qk
```

BUT I don't know how she will answer this, it's not the first time I've come to her - and zero hints from her. Help, please help me with the solution :)

Comment: N = 7 + 4208 = 4215; n= 3 + (4215 mod 13) = 6;
n + 1 = 7 number system.
But that's not the point, it's the algorithm